# SET and then SELECT ORDER BY CASE

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

What I'm trying to do is write a query that fetches all rows, but places whichever composite primary key matches a particular value on the top of the returned list.

However, I'm a huge n00b when it comes to MySQL and PHP. This is actually the first time I've ever tried using `SET` and executing queries other than `SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY` or `INSERT INTO WHERE`.

I tried the following code, but I'm receiving a fatal error that reads `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table`, which I believe has something to do with the first `execute` statement. I've never `SET` a variable before, so I'm at a loss...

```
include "includes/connect_to_database.php";

$sql = "SET @url = " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "SELECT sld, tld, ask, floor FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONCAT (sld, '.', tld) = @url THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CONCAT (sld, '.', tld)";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` sholud be escaped before assigning

Comment: @potiev escaped how? is there a built in php function for that?

Comment: `$sql = "SET @url = :host";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':host' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]);`

Comment: @potiev ahh thanks a lot buddy. ill try that right now

Comment: @potiev now its telling me i have a syntax error near `'table ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONCAT (sld, '.', tld) = @url THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CONCAT'` :(

Comment: In your database you really have table with name `table`?

Comment: @potiev ah sorry its been a long day. i just copied that from an answer in another question and forgot to modify that part. thanks!!

Comment: @potiev is it possible to combine the `SET` and `SELECT` statements?

Comment: I think `PDO` will crash if combine two different SQL statements

Comment: @potiev would it not even be possible to combine them, but separate them i.e. `"SET @url = :url; SELECT..."` and then execute them both at once `$stmt->execute([":url"=>$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]])`?

Comment: I think, you can't combine two different type queries. 1) INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 2) SELECT. `@set` belongs to 1 type

Comment: @potiev i tried it and it didnt work. is there a list anywhere telling me which queries can and cannot be combined?

Comment: About list I don't know) Do you need  `@url` variable only once?

Comment: @potiev yah only once for the following statement

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT sld, tld, ask, floor FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONCAT (sld, '.', tld) = :host THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CONCAT (sld, '.', tld)";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':host' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]);`

Comment: @potiev perfect. its funny. thats exactly what i was asking another guy about who posted a question, and he completely ignored my inquiry, which made me think it wasnt even possible to do something like that. really appreciate it buddy!! <3

Comment: I'M glad help you

Comment: May I add answer for question?

Comment: @potiev of course!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use variable `@url` at once, you can do it like this

```
include "includes/connect_to_database.php";

$sql = "SELECT sld, tld, ask, floor FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONCAT (sld, '.', tld) = :host THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CONCAT (sld, '.', tld)";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':host' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: any idea why `$var = [":url", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]]; $pdo->execute($var);` returns "Invalid parameter number"?

Comment: You should use associative array `$var = [':url' => $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]]`